# Select cached element with dynamic attribute

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

How it would be possible to cache and select element looks like this?

```
".myClass[data-list='2']";
```

This works:

```
var listNo = "2";

    ".myClass[data-list='" + listNo + "']";
```

But this is what I am trying and I can't make it works:

```
var listNo = "2", 
myClass = $('.myClass');

    myClass + "[data-list='" + listNo + "']"
```

and this is what Firebug is saying to me:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][data-list='02']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for filter, for example:

```
myClass.filter("[data-list='" + listNo + "']")
```